# SSIS Derived Column Expression - removing leading zeros

Tags: ssis

I have a package that is failing due to a negative sign with a numerical string such as:

> 000000000-25.00

The Derived column expression is:

```
ISNULL(wstr_Payment_Amount) || TRIM(wstr_Payment_Amount) == "" ? (DT_CY)0 : (DT_CY)wstr_Payment_Amount
```

The data type to column is money. I did a redirect row on the derived column to confirm it was the negative sign that was causing the failure.

Here is what I have..

```
FINDSTRING(wstr_Payment_Amount, "-", 1) >0  ? TRIM(SUBSTRING(wstr_Payment_Amount, FINDSTRING(wstr_Payment_Amount, "0-", 1), 8)) : wstr_Payment_Amount
```

I am using `SSIS 2008`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using two derived columns then leave it as a string in the first one...

```
ISNULL(wstr_Payment_Amount) || TRIM(wstr_Payment_Amount) == "" ? (DT_WSTR,100)"0" : (DT_WSTR,100)wstr_Payment_Amount
```

I think you were really close but consider the following once you identify the negative sign...

```
FINDSTRING(wstr_Payment_Amount, "-", 1) >0  ? (DT_CY) ("-" + replace(wstr_Payment_Amount,"-","")) : (DT_CY)wstr_Payment_Amount
```

This will just move the "-" to the front and all the zeroes will just go away.

Comment: Thanks Keith! it worked nicely. I just added ISNULL(wstr_Payment_Amount) || TRIM(wstr_Payment_Amount) == "" to account for nulls or blanks.. Appreciate your help!